# Email trigger conditions not working in Power Automate

Tags: triggers, conditional-statements, power-automate

I need what I would think is a very simple set of trigger conditions for incoming emails in Power Automate using *When a new email arrives in a shared mailbox* - trigger only if incoming email is from a specific domain and if the subject contains a specific string.

[image]

I have tried different combinations (including `endsWith` for the email domain) without success and keep getting errors like:

The template language function 'xxx' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'

Help to identify my error greatly appreciated!

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a new trigger, which inserted an array by default and changing the trigger conditions to Outputs got it running.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two into one expression with an and.

Can you try the below?

```
@and(contains(triggerOutputs()?['body/from'], '@abc.com'), contains(triggerOutputs()?['body/subject'], 'my string'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Expiscornovus - the AND construction was actually where I started, but thought the combination might be the problem. I double-checked with your expression and got the same failure. :( Weird. BTW I have this question also at https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Email-triggers-not-working-in-Power-Automate/m-p/2224846